# Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-SBFCRKL\Shaharyar Parekh'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to connect my asp.net web page to SQL Server 2014. My connection string is:

```
connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-SBFCRKL\SQLEXPRESS; 
    Initial Catalog=OnlineShop; 
    Integrated Security=True;"
```

When I run the project I get:

**> Server Error in '/onlineshoes' Application.

> Cannot open database "OnlineShop" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-SBFCRKL\Shaharyar Parekh'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open
>   database "OnlineShop" requested by the login. The login failed. Login
>   failed for user 'DESKTOP-SBFCRKL\Shaharyar Parekh'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 781:            this.Adapter.SelectCommand =
>   this.CommandCollection[0]; Line 782:
>   DS_CAT.CATEMST_SELECTDataTable dataTable = new
>   DS_CAT.CATEMST_SELECTDataTable(); Line 783:
>   this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable); Line 784:            return dataTable;
>   Line 785:        }
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Shaharyar Parekh\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\onlineshoes\11df693e\771d1f70\App_Code.rcz9orfq.2.cs
>   Line: 783
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "OnlineShop"
>   requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user
>   'DESKTOP-SBFCRKL\Shaharyar Parekh'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) +821
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +332
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +699
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +89
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +191
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +90
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +209    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +120
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +160    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable
>   dataTable) +108
>   DS_CATTableAdapters.CATEMST_SELECTTableAdapter.select() in
>   c:\Users\Shaharyar Parekh\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\onlineshoes\11df693e\771d1f70\App_Code.rcz9orfq.2.cs:783
>   KPATEL_Home.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   f:\Downloads\Compressed\onlineshoes\Home.aspx.cs:26
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +678**

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you able to access Database in SQL server management studio ?

Comment: Please copy & paste your exception. If you post a screenshot, we can't copy the text, the image might be too big for SO to display properly and search engines can't make sense of the image you have posted

Comment: The error is rather clear - you application's account doesn't have permission to connect to the database. Add this account to the database. BTW posting your computer and user account on a public site like this is *not* a good idea.

Comment: yes, database is accessible in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @MuhammadShaharyar Does it have any username and password when you try to login using SQL server management studio ?

Comment: has windows authentication so no username or password required

Comment: Is the instance name correct? What credentials do yo use to connect via Management Studio, SQL User or windows authentication?

Comment: using windows authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did resolve this by Starting the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service.
You can do this as below:

1. Open Services window (Start -> All Programs -> Windows
   Administrative Tools -> Services shortcut).
2. Right Click on SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER).
3. Press Start.

Answer (score 0):

Try following connection string:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; 
Initial Catalog=OnlineShop; 
Integrated Security=True;"
```

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "OnlineShop" requested by the login. The login failed. same exception

Comment: @MuhammadShaharyarI Can you put the code of method which throws error. I believe you are not setting connection to Open and using ADO.NET

Comment: DS_CAT.CATEMST_SELECTDataTable CDT = new DS_CAT.CATEMST_SELECTDataTable();
    DS_CATTableAdapters.CATEMST_SELECTTableAdapter CAdapter = new DS_CATTableAdapters.CATEMST_SELECTTableAdapter();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CDT = CAdapter.select();
        GridView1.DataSource = CDT;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        IDT = IAdapter.select();
        DataList1.DataSource = IDT;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=your-server-name; database=databaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```